# How to restore windows theme for one control

Tags: winapi

I use the following code to disable themes on a single control:

```
SetWindowTheme(yourControl.Handle, "", "");
```

or just

```
SetWindowTheme(yourControl.Handle, "explorer", "");
```

but after a while, I need to restore the original Windows Vista/Seven theme on that control. How can do it? I looked for a "default" name without finding it, all examples cite "" or "explorer", which disable the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `SetWindowTheme` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> When pszSubAppName and pszSubIdList are NULL, the theme manager removes the previously applied associations. You can prevent visual styles from being applied to a specified window by specifying an empty string, (L" "), which does not match any section entries.

***Note that `NULL` and `""` are not the same thing.***

You can restore the old theme for the application by just calling `SetWindowTheme` again with `NULL` values for the last two parameters:

```
SetWindowTheme(yourControl.Handle, NULL, NULL);
```